# Store TimeZone with Mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, time, mongoid

I have the following Mongoid model...

```
class Event
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps::Created
  include Mongoid::Timestamps::Updated
  include Mongoid::MultiParameterAttributes

  key :name

  field :name
  field :begins_at, type: Time
  field :ends_at, type: Time

  belongs_to :city

  attr_accessor :time_zone
end
```

I'd like to be able to have a per-event TimeZone.  Obviously due to the complications of time zones the best way to handle this is to store times in UTC when going to the DB and convert back to the event's time zone on the way out of the DB.

I know ActiveRecord has support for this and I was wondering if Mongoid has any kind of native support for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store as: timestamp and when query Format to timezone